# Using RTM installation Media after applying the service pack for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

There is a requirement to install Client components which are not installed on a MS SQL Server 2005 Installation.

As of now SP2 is applied on the SQL Server.

Is it OK to install the client component using the RTM installation media after applying the Service Pack. Will it have any impact on the current installation?